# increase number of sql database backups in google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm wondering whether it's possible to make GAE create more than 7 sql database backups and how much that will cost. They don't seem to mention this possibility in their document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to have more than 7 backups at a time for Cloud SQL. The goal is to use the backups as a last line of defense for restoring a broken database. If you need snapshots over time, you can use the Export functionality to save dumps to a Cloud Storage bucket.